# How friction between water and ice creates distribute charge in the cloud?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, friction, lightning

I've search in Google answer for it, but no one knows. Usually people say that when ice particles collide with water droplets, they get different charge. Small light particles get positive charge and go to the top of the cloud and big heavy go to the bottom. How exactly this happens? I only know that if we rub against each other, for example fur and ebonite rod, electrons go to material which has greater attraction for electrons. But what with water? How does it get charge due to friction? Water is water. I think there is no difference in attraction to electrons between one molecule of water and another. Or may be the phase matters? How do you think?

[image: charge distribution in cloud]

Comment: Register or log in to the National Academies Press website and read Chapter 9 Charging Mechanisms in Clouds and Thunderstorms of "The Earth's Electrical Environment"..  https://www.nap.edu/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes charge buildup in a cloud before a lightning storm?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121644/)